# Array.Length cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, ssis

I am trying to include a script task in my ssis package that continuously checks a folder until a specified file is placed there, at which point it succeeds and goes on to the next step in the package. Here is the code I am using in the script task:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ST_6a16f1bd9a6548ddb82bbf41d5d5006f
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]

public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    public void Main()
    {
        bool foundFile = false;
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"directory", "*abcd*");

        while (files.Length = 0)
            {
                foundFile = false;
            }

        if (files.Length > 0)
            { 
                foundFile = true;
            }

        if (foundFile == true)
            {
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
    }

    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };

}
```

}
 However, when I build this code, I get the error "Property or indexer 'Array.Length' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only".

Comment: `while (files.Length == 0)`, mind the double `==`. C strikes again. (But note that continuously checking this property will *not* tell you the file list changed because the array is initialized but once -- this will loop forever, or not at all. Try `FileSystemWatcher`, or else loop over `Directory.GetFiles` -- but if you do the latter, put in a `Thread.Sleep` lest you spike the CPU.)

Comment: If you want to check for File Changes, use the FileSystem Watcher. Rather then implementing your own wierd stuff via polling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
while (files.Length = 0)
```

Use

```
while (files.Length == 0)
```

You assigned 0 to files.Length instead of testing it.